# Display varbinary Image in Gridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Updated - Table definition - table name Surplus in ICTSQL - Windows Authentication
Surplus ID   int
Department   nchar(50)
Category     nchar(25)
Item         nchar(75)
visible      bit
TransferableImage  varbinary(MAX)

I have a SQL Server table with a `varbinary(MAX)` column called `TransferableImage` in table `Surplus` - server name ICTSQL.

Using Visual Basic, I want to display this image in a webpage gridview. I found code to do this, I know the image is there for the one record I have, but the image does not appear, and I've tried too many things so I'm bringing it to the experts. Other items in grid populate, it just doesn't show the image. No errors.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="TransferableImage" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

VB Code behind it:

```
Public Class About

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM surplus", conn)
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                GridView1.DataSource = dt
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dr As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        Dim imageUrl As String = "data:image/jpg;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(CType(dr("Data"), Byte()))
        CType(e.Row.FindControl("Image1"), Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

FYI - I haven't programmed in forever, so it's like relearning everything again. And, of course, boss needs it yesterday. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the primary key? `Surplus Id`?

Comment: The server name is "ICTSQL"? To get the server name, open a cmd window and type `hostname`. What's the database instance name? One way to find it is to open a cmd window (on the database server) and type `sc query | find /i "SQL Server"` The instance name will be inside `()`. For example, `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`, means that the instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: It's ICTSQL.  Primary key is Surplus ID

Comment: Are both the Windows server name and database instance name "ICTSQL"?

Comment: Yes - both ICTSQL

Answer (score 1):

The following will show how to retrieve an image from SQL Server and display it in a `GridView` on an ASP.NET web page.

**Create a table in the database**:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Surplus([Surplus Id] int not null, 
Department nchar(50),
Category nchar(25),
Item nchar(75),
Visible bit,
TransferableImage varbinary(max),
CONSTRAINT PK_Surplus_SurplusId PRIMARY KEY([Surplus Id]));
```

**Note**: If a table column name contains a space, it's necessary to surround it with `[]`. I prefer to create database column names without spaces.

---

Before starting, ensure that the appropriate Visual Studio Workloads/Individual Components are installed.

**VS 2017**:

- Open **Visual Studio Installer**
- Click **Modify**
- Click **Workloads** tab
- Ensure the following are checked: **.NET desktop development, ASP.NET and web development, Data storage and processing**
- Click **Individual Components**
- Under .NET, check: **.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK** and **.NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack**
- Under "Code Tools", check **ClickOnce Publishing** and **NuGet package manager**
- Select **Download all, then install**
- Click **Modify**

---

**VS 2017**:

**Create a new project**

- Open Visual Studio
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- On left, click **Visual Basic**
- On left, click **Web**
- Select **ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)**; For "Framework", select **.NET Framework 4.7.2**
- Click **OK**
- Select **Empty**
- Click **OK**

**Note**: Ensure [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) is turned on.

**Find your Windows server name**:

- Open a cmd window
- Type: **hostname**

**Find your SQL Server instance name**:

- Open a cmd window
- type: `sc query | find /i "SQL Server"`

**Note**: You'll see something like the following: `DISPLAY_NAME: SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`. The SQL Server instance name is within `()`. In this case, the SQL Server instance name is: `SQLEXPRESS`

We'll use the following:

- **Windows server name**: ICTSQL
- **SQL Server instance name**: ICTSQL
- **Database name**: ICTSQL
- **Authentication type**: Windows authentication

**Note**: I wouldn't recommend naming the Windows server, the database instance, and the database name the same name, as it can lead to confusion. However, my understanding is that as of the time of this posting, that they all currently have the name `ICTSQL`.

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Add connection string to Web.config**

- In Solution Explorer, double-click **Web.config**

In code below, modify the code within `<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrings>` for your environment. See [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/) for more information.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ictsqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ICTSQL;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

In the code below, I've adapted the code for the menu from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1819233e-113b-4c35-b474-c831eb332cf1/creating-menu-bar-in-aspnet?forum=aspwebforms)

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Add XML file to project** (name: surplusMenu.xml)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- On left side, click **Data**
- Click **XML File** (name: surplusMenu.xml)
- In Properties Window, set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy Always**

**surplusMenu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<surplusMenu text="Home" url="./default.aspx">
    <main text="Surplus" url="./addDatabaseRecord.aspx">
        <page text="Add Record" url ="./addDatabaseRecord.aspx" />
    </main>
</surplusMenu>
```

**Add a Module** (name: Module1.vb)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: `DatabaseGridViewTest`)
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- On left side, click **Code**
- Select **Module** (name: Module1.vb)
- Click **Add**

**Module1.vb**

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Public Function ResizeImage(imageBytes As Byte(), maxWidth As Integer, maxHeight As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim modifiedImageBytes As Byte()
        Dim ratioX As Double = 0
        Dim ratioY As Double = 0
        Dim ratio As Double = 0
        Dim newWidth As Integer = 0
        Dim newHeight As Integer = 0

        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(imageBytes)
            Using originalImg As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ms)
                ratioX = CType(maxWidth, Double) / originalImg.Width
                ratioY = CType(maxHeight, Double) / originalImg.Height

                'set value
                ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY)

                'calculate new width and height
                newWidth = CType((CType(originalImg.Width, Double) * ratio), Integer)
                newHeight = CType((CType(originalImg.Height, Double) * ratio), Integer)

                'create new Bitmap with desired size
                Using newImg As Bitmap = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
                    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImg)
                        g.DrawImage(originalImg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
                        g.Save()
                    End Using

                    Using newImgMs As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                        'save in jpeg format
                        newImg.Save(newImgMs, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                        'save as Byte()
                        modifiedImageBytes = newImgMs.ToArray()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Return modifiedImageBytes
    End Function
End Module
```

**Add WebForm** (name: addDatabaseRecord.aspx)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: `DatabaseGridViewTest`)
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- Select **Web Form** (name: addDatabaseRecord.aspx)
- Click **Add**

**addDatabaseRecord.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="addDatabaseRecord.aspx.vb" Inherits="DatabaseGridViewTest.addDatabaseRecord" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <!-- menu -->
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:cornflowerblue"  >
                <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="xmldatasource" DataFile="surplusMenu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

                <asp:Menu ID="menuNavigator" runat="server" Width="760px" DisappearAfter="0" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" DataSourceID="xmldatasource" ItemWrap="True" >
                    <StaticHoverStyle Height="34px" Width="50px" BackColor="#93C6FF" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="8px" Width="50px" Height="34px" CssClass="menustyle" ForeColor="Black" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle Width="50px" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1"></DynamicSelectedStyle>
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#6597F0" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#0A398D" Width="125px" HorizontalPadding="15px" VerticalPadding="6px" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="14px" />
                    <DataBindings>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="surplusMenu" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="url"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="main" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="text"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="page" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="text"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                    </DataBindings>
                </asp:Menu>  
            </div> 

            <div style="position:absolute;left:300px">
                <h2>Surplus Record Entry</h2>
            </div>

            <div>
                <!-- Surplus Id -->
                <asp:Label ID="LabelSurplusId" runat="server" Text="Surplus Id:" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:100px;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSurplusId" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:100px;width:75px" ></asp:TextBox>

                <!-- Department, Category -->
                <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartment" runat="server" Text="Department:" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:140px;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDepartment" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:140px;width:150px"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Label ID="LabelCategory" runat="server" Text="Category:" style="position:absolute;left:450px;top:140px;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCategory" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:550px;top:140px;width:150px"></asp:TextBox>

                <!-- Item, IsVisible -->
                <asp:Label ID="LabelItem" runat="server" Text="Item:" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:180px;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxItem" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:180px;width:150px"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxIsVisible" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:448px;top:180px;width:125px;font-weight:bold" Text="  Is Visible?" Checked="true"/>

                <!-- Transferable Image -->
                <asp:Label ID="LabelTransferableImage" runat="server" Text="Transferable Image:" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:220px;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadTransferableImage" runat="server" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:220px;font-weight:bold"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" style="position:absolute;left:350px;top:280px;height:40px;width:125px" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelMsg" runat="server" Text="" style="position:absolute;left:350px;top:340px"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Solution Explorer, right-click **addDatabaseRecord.aspx**. Select **View Code**

**addDatabaseRecord.aspx.vb**

**Note**: If a (database) table column name contains a space, it's necessary to surround it with `[]`.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class addDatabaseRecord
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SetSurplusId()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ClearPage()
        TextBoxSurplusId.Text = String.Empty
        TextBoxDepartment.Text = String.Empty
        TextBoxCategory.Text = String.Empty
        TextBoxItem.Text = String.Empty
        CheckBoxIsVisible.Checked = True

        'dispose
        FileUploadTransferableImage.Dispose()

        'create new instance
        FileUploadTransferableImage = New FileUpload()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetNextSurplusId() As Integer
        Dim nextSurplusId As Integer = 0
        Dim connectionStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ictsqlConnection").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlText As String = "SELECT Max([Surplus Id]) from Surplus;"

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
            'open
            con.Open()

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, con)
                'get last surplus id from database and increment it by 1
                nextSurplusId = (DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)) + 1
            End Using
        End Using

        Return nextSurplusId
    End Function

    Protected Function SaveSurplusRecord(surplusId As Integer, department As String, category As String, item As String, visible As Boolean, transferableImageBytes As Byte()) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
        Dim connectionStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ictsqlConnection").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlText As String = "INSERT INTO Surplus([Surplus Id], Department, Category, Item, Visible, TransferableImage) VALUES(@surplusId, @department, @category, @item, @visible, @transferableImage);"

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
            'open
            con.Open()

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, con)

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@surplusId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = surplusId

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(department) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@department", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@department", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = department
                End If

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(category) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = category
                End If

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = item
                End If

                'size = -1 is needed to exceed 8000 bytes; it maps to varbinary(max)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@transferableImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = transferableImageBytes

                'execute
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Private Sub SetSurplusId()
        Dim nextSurplusId As Integer = GetNextSurplusId()

        If nextSurplusId > 0 Then
            TextBoxSurplusId.Text = nextSurplusId.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If FileUploadTransferableImage.HasFile() Then
            LabelMsg.Text = "Filename: " & FileUploadTransferableImage.FileName & " File bytes: " & FileUploadTransferableImage.FileBytes.Length

            Dim surplusIdInt As Integer = 0

            If Int32.TryParse(TextBoxSurplusId.Text, surplusIdInt) Then
                'save record to database
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = SaveSurplusRecord(surplusIdInt, TextBoxDepartment.Text, TextBoxCategory.Text, TextBoxItem.Text, CheckBoxIsVisible.Checced, FileUploadTransferableImage.FileBytes())

                If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                    LabelMsg.Text = String.Format("Record saved (Surplus Id: {0}; Item: {1})", surplusIdInt.ToString(), TextBoxItem.Text)

                    ClearPage()
                    SetSurplusId()

                    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    'Response.Redirect("addDatabaseRecord.aspx")
                Else
                    LabelMsg.Text = String.Format("Error: Record not saved (Surplus Id: {0}; Item: {1})", surplusIdInt.ToString(), TextBoxItem.Text)
                End If
            Else
                LabelMsg.Text = String.Format("Error: Surplus Id must be an integer. (Surplus Id: '{0}')", TextBoxSurplusId.Text)
            End If
        Else
            LabelMsg.Text = "Error: Transferable image has not been selected."
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Add WebForm** (name: default.aspx)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: `DatabaseGridViewTest`)
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item...**
- Select **Web Form** (name: default.aspx)
- Click **Add**

**default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="DatabaseGridViewTest._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <!-- menu -->
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:cornflowerblue"  >
                <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="xmldatasource" DataFile="surplusMenu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

                <asp:Menu ID="menuNavigator" runat="server" Width="760px" DisappearAfter="0" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" DataSourceID="xmldatasource" ItemWrap="True" >
                    <StaticHoverStyle Height="34px" Width="50px" BackColor="#93C6FF" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="8px" Width="50px" Height="34px" CssClass="menustyle" ForeColor="Black" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle Width="50px" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1"></DynamicSelectedStyle>
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#6597F0" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#0A398D" Width="125px" HorizontalPadding="15px" VerticalPadding="6px" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="14px" />
                    <DataBindings>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="surplusMenu" TextField="text" NavigateUrlField="url"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="main" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="text"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                        <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="page" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="text"></asp:MenuItemBinding>
                    </DataBindings>
                </asp:Menu>  
            </div>    

            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelMsg" runat="server" Text="" style="position:absolute;left:50px; top:60px"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div style="position:absolute;left:50px; top:100px">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="Surplus Id" GridLines="Both">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Surplus Id" HeaderText="Surplus Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Visible" HeaderText="Visible" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transferable Image" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Image ID="TransferableImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("TransferableImageBase64", "{0}") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Solution Explorer, right-click **default.aspx**. Select **View Code**

**default.aspx.vb**

**Note**: If a (database) table column name contains a space, it's necessary to surround it with `[]`. Also, in the code below the images are resized when they are loaded. It may be preferrable to resize each image when saving it to the database so it doesn't have to resized each time it's loaded.

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim connectionStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ictsqlConnection").ConnectionString

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
            'open
            con.Open()

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT [Surplus Id], Department, Category, Item, Visible, TransferableImage FROM Surplus", con)
                Using da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

                    'fill DataTable with data from database
                    da.Fill(dt)

                    'add column that will store the image as a base64 string
                    dt.Columns.Add("TransferableImageBase64", GetType(System.String))

                    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        'convert image Byte() from database to base64 string and store in a new column in the DataTable
                        'dt(i)("TransferableImageBase64") = "data:image/jpg;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(CType(dt(i)("TransferableImage"), Byte()))

                        'resize image to desired size and convert image Byte() to base64 string, and store in a new column in the DataTable
                        dt(i)("TransferableImageBase64") = "data:image/jpg;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(ResizeImage(CType(dt(i)("TransferableImage"), Byte()), 50, 50))
                    Next

                    'remove column that contains Byte() from DataTable
                    dt.Columns.Remove("TransferableImage")

                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's a demo:

[image]

---

**Find name of IIS application pool**

**Win 10**:

- Open **Control Panel** (View by: Small icons)
- Double-click **Administrative Tools**
- Double-click **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**
- Expand <server name>
- Expand **Sites**
- Right-click desired website
- Select **Manage Website**
- Select **Advanced Settings...**
- Write down property value for `Application Pool` (ex: ICTSQL)

---

Below shows how to add the IIS user (`NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`) to SQL Server, how to add it to the database, and how to grant it permissions for a table. (This assumes that both SQL Server and IIS (the web server) are running on the same server. You'll want to repeat this process for the IIS APPPOOL user (ex: `IIS APPPOOL\ICTSQL`) as well.

**Download/install** [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Create a Database User**

- Open **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
- Expand **Security**
- Right-click **Logins**
- Select **New Login**
- Select **Windows authentication**
- Login name: `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`
- Select the desired default database (ex: ICTSQL)
- Click **OK**

**Add User to Database**

- Open **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
- Expand **Databases**
- Expand <desired database> (ex: ICTSQL)
- Expand **Security**
- Right-click **Users**
- Select **New User...**
- User name: `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`
- For "Login name", Click `...`
- Click **Browse**
- Select `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`
- Click **OK**
- Click **OK**
- Leave "Default schema", blank.
- Click **OK**

**Grant User Permissions on Table**

- Open **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
- Expand **Databases**
- Expand <desired database> (ex: ICTSQL)
- Expand **Tables**
- Right-click <desired table> (ex: dbo.Surplus)
- Select **Properties**
- Under "Select a page", click **Permissions**
- Click **Search**
- Click **Browse**
- Check desired user (ex: `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`)
- Click **OK**
- Click **OK**
- Under **Grant**, check the following: **Delete, Insert, Select, Update, References** (you may also want to grant: View change tracking, View definition)
- Click **OK**

**Note**: "With Grant" allows the user to grant the permissions to another user.

**Repeat the above process for the "IIS APPPOOL" user.** (ex: `IIS APPPOOL\ICTSQL`)

**Resources**:

- [Store Connection String in Web.config](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)
- [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/)
- [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)
- [Displaying Image in gridview with RowDataBound in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919776/displaying-image-in-gridview-with-rowdatabound-in-asp-net)
- [Assign Image URL in ASP.Net GridView based on column value in C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/111703/Assign-Image-URL-in-ASPNet-GridView-based-on-column-value-in-C-and-VBNet/)
- [Bind GridView In ASP.NET Step by Step](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/bind-gridview-in-Asp-Net-step-by-step/)
- [Resize image proportionally with MaxHeight and MaxWidth constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints)
- [How to control ASP.NET controls location in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190359/how-to-control-asp-net-controls-location-in-the-page)
- [creating menu bar in asp.net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1819233e-113b-4c35-b474-c831eb332cf1/creating-menu-bar-in-aspnet?forum=aspwebforms)
- [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)
- [Add IIS 7 AppPool Identities as SQL Server Logons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons)

Comment: Thanks for responding - this doesn't work either

Comment: Everything I posted is tested. I tested it using the debugger (in Visual Studio) as well as publishing it to an IIS website and running it there.

Comment: In the code above, `data:image/jpg;` assumes that the image is a ".jpg". If it's another format, change it to the appropriate image type. Also ensure that you've changed the database connection settings in "web.config".

Comment: In your SQL, is the image varbinary?  Your thorough post gives everything but the structure of the SQL table and fields. I'm wondering if that is my issue - something with the varbinary field for the image. It even gives SQL authentication, just not the structure of the database.  I doubt if my issue is this but I am using Windows Authentication and not SQL login authentication.

Comment: You must have missed it because I put it at the beginning under **Create a table in the database**

Comment: I recommend that you follow my post step-by-step including using SQL server authentication. After you have it working, you can switch to WIndows authentication. It's may be possible that the image data wasn't saved to the database properly. For how to upload an image to the database see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276565/i-have-written-a-vb-net-code-to-display-image-in-the-image-control-but-not-able/70307947#70307947)

Comment: I did miss it!  I checked that and the image is there.  Trying to keep away from creating new database because I already have other forms built...  I think I'll create a separate database using just what you have - maybe I'll figure out what's wrong with mine.

Comment: If you provide your table definition I may consider modifying the post to suite your environment. Add it your your OP as an "Update".

Comment: Added table definition to post.  Thanks for your help!  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: OMG - It works!  Except the Function ResizeImage.  I am getting Parameter is not valid error on the line "Using originalImg as Bitmap = New Bitmap(ms).  Ideas?

Comment: Looks like I didn't have `Option Strict` turned on - although the errors I received after turning it on weren't on that particular line. I've updated the code. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: The function ResizeImage is missing from the code above.  Have to tell you - you were very thorough with your response and it helped sooo much!  The issue was the Visual Studio version - I was at 2010.  Upgraded to 2017, and it worked.

Comment: Now to get the resize to work and then figure out how to click on it to make it big...  I appreciate your help tremendously!

Comment: It's not missing, it's been relocated. When I updated the code, I added a Module (name: `Module1.vb`) and moved `ResizeImage` to Module1.vb which will allow it to be called from `addDatabaseRecord.aspx.vb` and `default.aspx.vb` - depending on whether you want to resize an image before you upload it to the database, or resize it prior to displaying it.  If you like, you can just copy the code from "ResizeImage"  (above) and place it where you currently have it. `SaveSurplusRecord` has also been updated.

Comment: Try searching for `asp.net enlarge image on click` or `asp.net enlarge image on mouseover`

Comment: Module - great!  Getting a "Parameter is not valid" on "Using originalImg as Bitmap = New Bitmap(ms)" in Module1.vb.

Comment: What is "Target Framework" set to? (`Project => <projectName Properties> => Application => look at Target Framework`). Also on the left side, click on Compile. Ensure `Option explicit` is on and `Option strict` is on

Comment: Since you stated that you're using VS 2017, I re-created the project using VS 2017, so the code has been tested with VS 2017. I've also updated the post with instruction for VS 2017. You may want to try creating a new project following the instructions, however the only code that changed is in `Web.config`. If you still can't get `ResizeImage` to work, you may want to try some other code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints) (or search for some other code on how to resize an image)

Comment: I have to thank you for all your help - you were very detailed and it taught/re-taught me so much!  It helped me put the image in the grid (although it was the actual image size).  To resize the image, I just changed the following.
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageBase64", "{0}") %>' ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height = "100" />
    </ItemTemplate>